# I don't know why status bar get incomplete to be transparent

Tags: android, statusbar, transparent

I want status bar to be transparent like [image: this link image]

But status bar get incomplete to be transparent when this activity open first [image: open first].
To be weird, if I start to scroll up image, status bar is getting transparent like [image: this link image]

Please, help me and thanks alot

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.ui.main.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:expandedTitleGravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/header"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                    style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following code after `setContentView()` in the activity in which you want to have a fully transparent status bar:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
        setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, true);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, false);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
```

Comment: Where is setWindowFlag function?

Answer (score 0):

To Resolve do following this

1. Add Toolbar

> ```
> <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>             android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:paddingTop="10dp"
>             android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
>             android:background="@drawable/studio_black_fading"
>             local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
>             local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
> ```

2. Make your activity as a full screen using following

> ```
> getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
>         getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
> ```

3. Add following style in styles.xml

> ```
> <style name="AppTheme.Translucent">
> <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
>         <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
>         <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
>         <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
>         <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
>         <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
>         <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
>     </style>
> ```

4. Set this style to your manifest in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: I resolved it as adding "android:fitsSystemWindows=true" to all of CoordinatorLayout, AppbarLayout, CollapsingToolbarlayout, ImageView. 
Anyway, Thank you